# Android - Getting messages from AWS SQS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have function which returns messages from AWS SQS:

```
  public List<Message> getMessagesFromQueue(String queueUrl){
       ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl);
       List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
       return messages;
    }
```

The problem is that it returns different number of messages each time, never all 4 which I have in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to hear that you are having difficulty using the API to achieve reading the SQS queue using the API. You can find the documentation for receiveMessage from the Java client here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html#receiveMessage-com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest-

The documentation for receiveMessage indicates that anywhere from 1 to 10 messages may be returned. The number returned may be limited by calling the   setMaxNumberOfMessages method on the ReceiveMessageRequest object; however, this only limits the maximum amount of messages that may be returned. To attempt to read all the messages in the queue, try calling the method until no messages come back in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you receive messages, a *visibility timeout* is triggered for the messages received. This means that the messages will not be returned on future calls to receive messages, until the timeout is reached (by default 30 seconds). This means that messages will keep popping in and out as these visibility timeouts are triggered and restored.

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutVT.html

Also, like Jeff Solinsky points out, you should make sure to delete messages you've received and processed so they don't pollute you queue.