# Getting messages from SQS - Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a function which returns messages from AWS SQS:

```
 public List<Message> getMessagesFromQueue(String queueUrl){
       ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl);
       List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
       return messages;
    }
```

The problem is that it ruturns different number of messages each time, never all 4 which I have in the queue.

---

I found out what is the issue:

> Because Amazon SQS is a distributed system and the particular queue we're working with here has very few messages in it, the response to the receive request might be empty. Therefore, you should rerun the sample until you get the message. You should design your own application so that it continues to poll the queue until it gets one or more messages.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement that to get whole queue.

Thank you in advance, Jan.

Comment: Are you deleting messages off the queue after successfully processing them? If not you will likely keep receiving the same messages. Otherwise it's just a matter of polling the queue for new messages.

Comment: Also appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110538/andoid-getting-mesages-from-aws-sqs.